# Why INotification/IRequest marker interfaces for Mediator?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mediator

Whilst I am a massive fan of MediatR, it feels strange to take it as a dependency on all my projects (even those that don't "dispatch" and are merely posting POCOs reference the marker interfaces).

If one were to write a similar mediator library that did other things but had common Send/Publish functions, what is the need therefore for marker interfaces when the below code works with plain POCOs?

The code delineates between a request/notification via the Send/Publish functions, so are these marker interfaces redundant?

If I were to implement my own mediator, are there any issues with removing the marker interfaces from `Notification` and `Request`?

It is more about design principle of marker interfaces as opposed to wanted to change MediatR itself (to avoid offence I have removed the MediatR, the lib i repeat for the record is awesome and i am adapting it for my own purposes with multithreaded synchronized background stream-based dispatch hence the design questions).

**Handler interfaces**

```
public interface INotificationHandler<in TNotification> where TNotification : class
{
    Task Handle(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface IRequestHandler<in TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : class
{
    Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

**Plain POCO without marker interfaces**

```
class TestNotification
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class TestRequest
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**Handlers**

```
class TestRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<TestRequest, int>
{
    public Task<int> Handle(TestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(request.UserId);
    }
}

class TestNotificationHandler : INotificationHandler<TestNotification>
{
    public Task Handle(TestNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _ = new TestNotificationHandler()
                .Handle(new TestNotification(), CancellationToken.None);

    var result = new TestRequestHandler()
                        .Handle(new TestRequest() { UserId = 111 }, CancellationToken.None)
                        .Result;

    Console.WriteLine($"result is {result}");
}
```

**C# fiddle**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTkfh9

Comment: Are you asking about removing the interfaces form the library?

Comment: Nkosi, thanks for the reply and good question - not from the library, moreover a design question, as if implementing the same pattern it would seem the interface is not required (and marker interfaces can be an antipattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about `INotification`. If you were to write your own implementation of MediatR, you could basically remove that marker interface.

For `IRequest`, however, you need the response type in your request definition in order to be able to handle the response after calling the mediator.

Consider a request without a defined response type:

```
public class TestRequest
{
}
```

Now, if you would call the mediator, there would be no way to determine the response type:

```
IMediator mediator = GetMediator();

// There is no way to type the response here.
var response = mediator.Send(new TestRequest());
```

The only way mediator is able to type the response, is because the response definition is in the request definition:

```
public interface IRequest<out TResponse> : IBaseRequest { }
```

And the `IMediator` `Send` is defined like so:

```
Task<TResponse> Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

That makes it possible to know the return type.

So, long story short:

- You don't need `INotification`
- You *do* need `IRequest<TResponse>`

Answer (score 2):

1. What is the need therefore for marker interfaces in the first place, when the below code works with plain POCOs?

Let's take a look at MediatR

```cs
namespace MediatR
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Marker interface to represent a request with a void response
    /// </summary>
    public interface IRequest : IRequest<Unit> { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Marker interface to represent a request with a response
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResponse">Response type</typeparam>
    public interface IRequest<out TResponse> : IBaseRequest { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows for generic type constraints of objects implementing IRequest or IRequest{TResponse}
    /// </summary>
    public interface IBaseRequest { }
}

namespace MediatR
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Marker interface to represent a notification
    /// </summary>
    public interface INotification { }
}
```

They're just empty interfaces, so I think `MediatR` maybe add some function to `IRequest` in the future like this:

```cs
public interface IRequestType {
    int GetId();

    string GetName();
}
/// <summary>
/// Marker interface to represent a request with a void response
/// </summary>
public interface IRequest : IRequest<Unit> {
    IRequestType GetRequestType();
}
```

So I think you should implement `IRequest` and `INotification` to avoid a big update in your source code in the future

2. Is there any issues with removing the marker interfaces from Notification and Request?

Currently, for your examples, it's OK
But when you use `Publish` function it's not OK

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously send a notification to multiple handlers
/// </summary>
/// <param name="notification">Notification object</param>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">Optional cancellation token</param>
/// <returns>A task that represents the publish operation.</returns>
Task Publish<TNotification>(TNotification notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where TNotification : INotification;
```

BTW, I think `MediatR` need an update to make a builder for `Mediator` like this:

```cs
IMediator mediator = new Mediator.Builder()
            .AddRequestHandler(typeof(PingRequest), new PingRequestHandler())
            .Build();
```

Comment: If they add functionality to those interfaces you are looking at a big update to your source code anyways. You would NOT want to implement the interfaces to avoid that impact.

Comment: If they change the interfaces, I think they will use default method and you don't need update if you dont want

Comment: I agree, I had to go back and refresh myself on the topic.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/categories

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem a while ago. I really wanted to avoid having all my libraries reference the MediatR package. I also didn't see the point in having them since you could get around it by just wrapping it in a generic object like this:

```
public class NotificationWrapper<TNotification> : INotification {
    public TNofication Data { get; }
    public NotificationWrapper(TNotification notification) {
        Data = notification ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(notification);
    }
}
```

And then handling it using an implementation of `INotificationHandler<NotificationWrapper<SomeType>>`

So, I ended up copying the library and writing a version without those interfaces. Turns out, you don't need either `INotification` or `IRequest<out TResponse>`... But with a tradeoff.

INotification follows what Jesse said above. But, with IRequest, you'll notice that the Send method does have a generic parameter for the response. However, it's using `IRequest<out TResponse>` to infer the parameter. If you remove the interface, you can still use `TResponse` to do the lookup for the handler, you just have to explicitly define the response type from the caller. In my opinion, this is a pretty good tradeoff, since you'll have to do this anyways if the request type implements `IRequest<out TResponse>` multiple time with different response types. And, if accepting the condition that you'll have to explicitly define the response you're expecting, you can remove the `IRequest<out TResponse>` interface and call like so:

```
IMediator mediator = GetMediator();
mediator.Send<ExpectedResponse>(request);
```

The version I did this to is hosted here, and was based on MediatR 8.0.0:
https://github.com/user040F019F/Mediation

Admittedly, I probably should've done a fork/PR, but I wasn't super used to github at the time. Also, ignore the readme, it's nonsensical.